# How to do composite primary keys with FactoryGirl Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

How to do composite keys using FactoryGirl with below relationship

**Portal(uuid, name)**

**listing(uuid, portal_uuid, name)**

**location(uuid, portal_uuid)**

in here listing and location has **composite primary key (uuid, portal_uuid)**.

I have tried different kind of ways but can't solve it. Have anyone met this problem, pls help?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how your models are related.  It would probably help if you could post some of your model code.

Comment: Error using AR v3, FG v4, composite_primary_keys v5
>    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>      PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "col1,col2" does not exist
>       LINE 1: ...") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "col1...
Code:
>    class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
>      self.primary_key = :col1
>    end
>
>    class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
>      self.primary_key = :col2
>    end
>
>    class TableRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
>      require 'composite_primary_keys'
>      self.primary_keys = :col1, :col2
>    end